# How to fix the association bonus so it's easier to reach for people who use many SE sites?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, reputation, linked-accounts, association-bonus

This is my account earlier today:

[image]

I was getting extremely sick of getting "You cannot comment because you haven't earned 50 rep" messages which I saw many many times before getting the association bonus, and would generally cause me to close the SE site I was on immediately.

The association bonus feels like it kicked in way too late for me. As you can see I had at least 600 rep across sites, but none over 200. It was a fairly awful user experience, especially not having "Comment Everywhere" everywhere.

I waited until I actually got it before commenting here so I wouldn't be dismissed as trying to be bend the rules or whatever.

Perhaps the bonus could be given in two stages. Or it could weight rep from all the sites you're associated with. Other suggestions?

Comment: You can earn 200 rep on one site *in a day* if you're willing to put the time in; I'm not sure how we can make that any easier.

Comment: Some people can.

Comment: But it took me four years.

Comment: I'm not sure that "four years" is at all representative of even the average user. For that matter, 50 rep on a given site still more or less takes *one* solid answer. If you're into participating on a given site, it really shouldn't be a huge roadblock.

Comment: I am truly sorry to hear that your experience sucked. But here's the thing - there is no such thing as "ideal for all users". We, more or less, try to balance new user experience against casual user experience and it's relatively hard to *reliably* tell a new user apart from someone who knows what's what but hasn't really participated that much or attracted many upvotes. That is, for better or for worse, a fact of life. Granted, 50 rep to comment is arbitrary and I think we could lower it, but there's not going to be a perfect win here.

Comment: I think the high rep needed for commenting is really my main issue. I notice even [my earliest 'answer'](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3685688/443019) was meant to be a comment, and the difficulty of just adding a comment seems to have plagued me since.

Comment: Yeah, this is perhaps becoming more of an issue on Stack Overflow. Our usual guidance is along the lines of "there are plenty of questions to go around, just find one that doesn't *need* clarification or commenting on" and honestly... while I sympathize, I also can't quite argue against that. Comments aren't designed to be vital/necessary on any given post. Sometimes they are despite that, it's true. But *on balance*, unless we built better moderation tools for comments, etc. etc., what we got now is IMHO our best bet.

Comment: It would be nice to be able to gain your initial rep on a site by making corrections/additions to answers.

Comment: You can do that via suggested edits. Each approved edit nets you 2 reputation points. You can gain up to 1000 reputation that way - quite a bit above 200. As an added bonus, you can also suggest edits questions to speed this up.

Comment: I meant through comments, but yes that is fair. Though it does seem odd that you can hit "edit" on someone's answer but you can't simply add a comment after it. Maybe comments on answers could just require approval too?

Comment: Perhaps just change the "You don't have enough rep to comment" message so that it suggests using "edit" to fix any mistakes in the post.

Comment: If memory serves, we looked into that a few months back... The gist of the result was that there are barely enough people to curate edits, new posts, close votes, and so on, nevermind anything that one might decide to type into a comment box. I'm sure that *you* and some others wouldn't do anything malicious with it, but we see enough spam to make me hesitate to recommend anything that makes it *easier* to post on our sites and waste people's time on reviewing it. The bottom line being, we are resistant to change in this are for a reason, not because we don't listen or didn't think about it.

Comment: Having said that, changing the "you don't have enough rep to comment" message to point people towards "edit" sounds like a good idea and/or good basis for a new [tag:feature-request] post.

Comment: That's a good idea, but considering the hostility to my post here I'm obviously not going to bother.

Answer (score 2):

Qubei's situation seems to be more or less like this:

The average user often picks up one or two sites of particular interest. They participate strongly in those sites, unlock privileges, and demonstrate they're a decently acceptable member of the community.

Qubei on the other hand did not participate heavily in any one particular site. Whilst he or she may have learned a lot about the SE engine during their tenure, and conduct spread across multiple sites, the lack of any deliberate specialisation meant no rep bonus.

#### What can we do?

So, one response to a newbie interacting with the network in this manner is to suggest that they should consciously focus on one site for a little while - possibly as a sort of gaming of the system - to unlock their rep bonus for all their other sites. That's probably a valid suggestion to make. It's not going to help those who wish to continue being generalists and don't want to go out of their usual course for the rep bonus, or those who have issues with the fact this would seem like gaming the system.

Alternately, we could count contributions to multiple sites toward the rep bonus.

But, critically, don't just add up their network-wide rep. If a user has 20 accounts with 10 rep each, that's a barely-passable contribution (albeit *lots* of barely-passable contributions), but they'll suddenly get the rep bonus and unlock a bunch of privileges they haven't demonstrated they'll use wisely, and which they haven't otherwise unlocked another way. (Consider the theoretical user who writes a spambot which signs up to 200 different sites and then spams comments everywhere.)

What we can do instead is this: you either reach 200 rep on one site, or 100 rep on 2-4 separate sites. This way, the 100 bonus rep would not give you privileges you don't otherwise have elsewhere already, and you still need to demonstrate you're a decent and consistent contributor by reaching the 100 rep milestone in multiple locations. If 100 rep on two different sites is a bit too easily obtained and doesn't yet constitute sufficient demonstration, require it from 3 or 4 sites instead.

#### Is this worth it?

I don't know, really. Personally, I'd just be inclined to suggest focus on one site where you have sufficient expertise and experience to contribute regularly, and unlock 200 rep there. That's how I eventually got it for myself. (I unlocked it on Game Development, I think.) If you don't want to do that, well, no rep bonus.

Comment: I like this idea in principle, but I'm afraid in practice it's going to be a bit off -- if nothing else, someone with the patience to create accounts on 99 sites would have 100 network-wide reputation and then unlock whatever privileges we associate with that. Tracking whether they actually *posted* on any of those sites would most likely be too much of a performance hit to make it worthwhile.

Comment: @AnnaLear Oh, I don't mean unlock 100 global rep. I mean: on each of 2-4 different sites, I must have >= 100 reputation. Currently, for ***1*** site, I must have >= 200 reputation. For example, let's pick a requirement of four sites: if I have 190 reputation on Super User, and 150 on Stack Overflow, 150 on Code Review, still no rep bonus. I'll sign up to another site, spend a little while earning 100 reputation there, and now I have the rep bonus.

Comment: Oh, 100 rep *each* on multiple sites... a) I misread your original proposal, sorry. b) That actually seems harder than 200 rep on *one* site.

Comment: @AnnaLear Yeah, I totally agree it seems harder. And yet, no rep bonus for that user, despite them clearly doing quite a bit of work. (Or for Qubei, in this case.) So the idea is: acknowledge that work, and count >=100 rep on multiple sites as a possible way for achieving the rep bonus.